# How to include and use Rust libraries

Tags: rust

Here is the files that I have

main.rs

```
mod sort;

fn main() {
    let v = ~[0,1,3,7,5,7,9,4,2,6,9,5,3,5,0,7,6,9,0,2,3,4,2,4,7,9,7];
    sort::mergeSort(v);
    sort::print(v);
}
```

and

sort.rs

```
use std::vec;
pub fn mergeSort<T: Clone+Ord>(a: &mut[T]){
    let mid = a.len()/2 as uint;
    let mut aux = vec::with_capacity(mid+1);
    __mergesort(a, 0, a.len(), aux);

    fn __mergesort<T: Clone+Ord>(a: &mut[T], lo: uint, hi: uint, aux: &mut[T]){
        let mid = a.len()/2 as uint;
        if mid > 0 {
            __mergesort(a, lo, mid, aux);
            __mergesort(a, mid+1, hi, aux);
            __merge(a, mid, aux);
    }

        fn __merge<T: Clone+Ord>(a: &mut[T], lo: uint, mid: uint, hi: uint, aux: &mut[T]) {
            __clone_array(a, 0, mid+1, aux, 0);
            let mut i = 0;
            let mut j = 0;
            let mut k = 0;
            while k < a.len() {
                if j >= a.len()-mid {
                    __clone_array(a, k, a.len(), aux, 0);
                    break;
                } else if i >= mid {
                    break;
                }
                if aux[i] <= a[mid+j] {
                    a[k] = aux[i];
                    i += 1;
                } else {
                    a[k] = a[mid+j];
                    j += 1;
                }
                k += 1;
            }
        }

        fn __clone_array<T: Clone>(a: &[T], af: uint, al: uint, b: &mut[T], bf: uint){
            for i in range(bf, bf+al-af) {
                b[i] = a[af+i].clone();
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn print<T: ToStr>(v: &[T]) {
    print!("[ ");
    for i in range(0, v.len()) {
        print!("{} ", v[i].to_str());
    }
    println!("]");
}
```

Here is the error that I get

sort.rs:44:23: 44:41 error: unresolved name `vec::with_capacity`.

sort.rs:44         let mut aux = vec::with_capacity(mid+1); 
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: aborting due to previous error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there's a few more lines in the error message above the stuff you pasted, could you paste them too?

Comment: Thanks! What version of Rust do you have? (The output of `rustc -v`.)

Comment: rustc 0.10

host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: Why the leading `__`? It’s entirely superfluous.

Comment: @cris-morgan It is just for me to remind me it is an internal function and should not be used outside.

Comment: @OmidNikta: you *can’t* use it outside the containing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_capacity` is not a function in `std::vec`, it’s [a static method on the `Vec` type](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.10/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity). Capitalise your `v` in `vec::with_capacity` (`Vec` is automatically in scope, being a part of the prelude).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was it. Thanks for the documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

In the near-ish future, you'll use Cargo to manage including external dependencies.